# Create a view to show comments on a user ONLY from that user

Tags: 7, views, users, comments

Am using comment as reviews for a content type. Now am trying to create a block in views that will appear on the user profile page. I want to show ONLY comments (reviews) that are from the specific users page i'm on. If the user has no comments made, then the block would be hidden. What settings in views would allow this to happen?

I've tried using content filters and relationship filters but I haven't been able get the right settings. Example: Am on User A's Profile page, I want to display all comments from User A on his profile page.

EDIT: Since my answer really didnt receive anything that can help. I will try to better word the question. I just need to create a block with comments from a specific content type in context to the user profile I'm on. I've created my view and added a contextual filter base off the author uid. But it still shows all the comments not just the ones from the current profile user.

Comment: create a normal views with contextual filter from url then follow http://drupal.org/node/544884

Answer (score 0):

You should indeed use a contextual filter, selecting "When the filter value is NOT available", then "provide default value", and choose "user ID from loggued user".

That should work.